# MySQL count users in common between pairs of posts through many to many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables: users, posts, and users_posts. The users-posts relationship is many-to-many. How can I get a list of all pairs of posts and how many users they have in common? It essentially gives me a list of posts and how many users have commented on both. The point is to have data ready to import into network analysis software. The resulting list is called an "edgelist" in network terms, the users in common is an edge weight.

Schema:

```
users
id
name

posts
id
title
body

users_posts
user_id
post_id
```

Desired output:

```
postname1         postname2     users_in_common
Here's a title    Title #2      2
Another post      Title #2      11
```

I tried searching but didn't even know the right search terms among many-to-many, join, three tables, count, pairs, shared, etc. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How does a "*pair of posts*" come about?  There's no such pairing in the database.

Comment: @eggyal, I think Libby just meant the combinations of every 2 posts. Though it's unclear _why_ it could be needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My query produces all pairs of posts including those without common users (will have `0` in `users_in_common` in such case). Try my solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df599/1) or see the code:

```
select
    p1.title as postname1,
    p2.title as postname2,
    coalesce(s.users_in_common, 0) as users_in_common
from posts p1
    inner join posts p2 on p1.id < p2.id
    left join (
        select
            up1.post_id as post1_id,
            up2.post_id as post2_id,
            count(*) as users_in_common
        from users_posts up1, users_posts up2
        where up1.user_id = up2.user_id
            and up1.post_id < up2.post_id
        group by up1.post_id, up2.post_id
    ) s
    on (s.post1_id = p1.id and s.post2_id = p2.id)
order by p1.id, p2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
  p1.title as postname1,
  p2.title as postname2,
  (select count(*) from user_posts up where up.post_id in (p1.post_id, p2.post_id) as users_in_common
from
  posts p1, posts p2
```